# Firebase cordova signin setup

Tags: firebase, cordova, firebase-authentication

I am following the direction for adding firebase auth to my cordova project but I have an issue with step 3 and 6 of the documentation.

document -- [firebase -cordova setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova)

I am currently using Custom URL scheme (no firebase) that looks like mycoolapp:// and it woking ok on both cordova android and ios app. This is in the docs for this  plugin

Now I am trying to add firebase auth to my app and I am need some clarification.

In step 3 of the documentation it says :

To set up an iOS app, create an iOS application and add it to the Firebase console. You will need the iOS bundle ID to add later when installing the **custom URL scheme plugin**

then in step 6

Plugin to handle deep linking through Custom Scheme for iOS 
Substitute # com.firebase.cordova with the iOS bundle ID of your app.

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable \
    URL_SCHEME=com.firebase.cordova --save

Given that I am already using the customurlscheme plugin with the URl SCHEME = mycoolapp:// then can I continue to use it or do I have change all my code to now use the bundle id.. Also, my cordova  iOS and Android have different bundle ID

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to add multiple custom schemes. The Firebase Auth client SDK will detect the incoming link on its own. You don't need to handle that logic.

Based on https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme#manually

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>URL_SCHEME</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
```

`CFBundleURLSchemes` takes an array of custom schemes.